# using Jeet and Compass results in an error?

Tags: css, sass

Whenever I try to use a combination of Jeet and Compass I get the following error:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \" gutter\": expected \")\", was \": 3,\"\A on line 3 of sass/jeet/_settings.scss\A from line 15 of sass/jeet/index.scss\A from line 7 of sass/screen.scss\A \A 1: // Grid Settings\A 2: $jeet: (\A 3: gutter: 3,\A 4: parent-first: false,\A 5: layout-direction: LTR\A 6: );\A 7: \A 8: // Sass Namespacing Function
```

When I run just Jeet or just compass everything works fine. I've tried different versions of SASS, Jeet, and Compass but I can't seem to find either the right combination or the right settings here.

**Current Versions**:

```
Sass 3.3.0.alpha.149 (Bleeding Edge)

Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)
```

I previously had both at their latest versions.

What can I try?

Recently tried: 
- Updating to Compass 0.12.6 which results in the new error: ERROR: Cannot load compass.

Previously, this is the related code from Jeet that was throwing the error:

```
// Grid Settings
$jeet: (
  gutter: 3,
  parent-first: false,
  layout-direction: LTR
);

// Sass Namespacing Function
@function jeet($var) {
  @return map-get($jeet, $var);
}

$g: jeet(gutter);

error sass/jeet/_settings.scss (Line 3: Invalid CSS after "  gutter": expected ")", was ": 3,")
```

Comment: Even crazier, I just tried to run it through codekit and everything runs just fine. Does codekit run it's own versions of sass and compass? Crazy.

Comment: Compass 0.12 is not compatible with Sass 3.3.  It might be helpful if you provided the code that causes the error.

Comment: Current running Sass 3.3.5 and Compass 0.12.6. Added the error above.

Comment: As I already stated, Compass 0.12 is not compatible with Sass 3.3.  You're getting syntax errors because Compass is using Sass 3.2, which does not support mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using it in a Yeoman scaffold with

1. Sass 3.3.4 (Maptastic Maple)
2. Compass 0.12.5 (Alnilam)

It is being compiled by "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.7.0" and so far have had no errors.

edit:
Also those settings appear to be stylus not scss.